# How do I create a function to perform label encoding

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, label-encoding

I have the dataframe -

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'colA':['a', 'a', 'a', 'b' ,'b'], 'colB':['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b'], 'colC':['x', 'x', 'y', 'y', 'y']})
```

I would like to write a function to replace each value with it's frequency count in that column. For example colA will now be `[3, 3, 3, 2, 2]`

I have attempted to do this by  creating a dictionary with the value and the frequency count, assign that dictionary to a variable `freq`, then map the column values to `freq`. I have written the following function

````
def LabelEncode_method1(col): 
   freq = col.value_counts().to_dict()
   col = col.map(freq)
   return col.head()```
````

When I run the following  `LabelEncode_method1(df.colA)`,  I get the result `3, 3, 3, 2, 2`. However when I call the dataframe `df`, the values for `colA` are still `'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b'`

1. What am I doing wrong. How do I fix my function?
2. How do I write another function that loops through all columns and maps the values to `freq`, as opposed to calling the function 3 separate times for each column.

Answer (score 3):

You can do `groupby` + `transform`

```
df['new'] = df.groupby('colA')['colA'].transform('count')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `map` + `value_counts` (Which you have already found, you just need to assign the result back to your DataFrame).

```
df['colA'].map(df['colA'].value_counts())
```

---

```
0    3
1    3
2    3
3    2
4    2
Name: colA, dtype: int64
```

For all columns, which will create a new DataFrame:

```
pd.concat([
  df[col].map(df[col].value_counts()) for col in df
], axis=1)
```

---

```
   colA  colB  colC
0     3     2     2
1     3     2     2
2     3     2     3
3     2     1     3
4     2     2     3
```